# Android: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type VirtualMoney

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I'm having a problem retrieving the balance of a user. It always says I can't convert object type to:

> Android: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type VirtualMoney

Here is my VirtualMoney class:

```
package com.ortegapatriciaa.hcifinal_project;

public class VirtualMoney {

String balance;

VirtualMoney(){

}

public VirtualMoney(String balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}


public String getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(String balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
}
```

My viewholder class:

```
public class MoneyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

public TextView txtbalance;

public MoneyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    txtbalance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_current_balance);

}

}
```

And Lastly, my main activity where I must display the balance of a certain user.

```
  {...
    user = Common.currentUser.getUsername();

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    databaseReference2 = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("virtualMoney");
    loadListBooks();
     }

 private void loadListBooks() {

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<VirtualMoney, MoneyViewHolder>(VirtualMoney.class,
            R.layout.money_card,
            MoneyViewHolder.class,
            databaseReference2.child(user)) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MoneyViewHolder viewHolder, final VirtualMoney model, int position) {
            viewHolder.txtbalance.setText(model.getBalance());

            final String virtualMoney = "0";


        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My firebase database in virtual money

[image]

Comment: At which code line do you find this error to be pointing at?

Comment: On which line you are getting the error. Please specify the complete error message. If you are getting error on this  
viewHolder.txtbalance.setText(model.getBalance()); try .toString() in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a wrong reference the your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` constructor. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<VirtualMoney, MoneyViewHolder>(VirtualMoney.class,
        R.layout.money_card,
        MoneyViewHolder.class,
        databaseReference2.child(user))
```

to

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<VirtualMoney, MoneyViewHolder>(VirtualMoney.class,
        R.layout.money_card,
        MoneyViewHolder.class,
        databaseReference2)
```

Because under `databaseReference2` reference exist `VirtualMoney` objects. Under `databaseReference2.child(user)` there are no `VirtualMoney` objects and that's why that error.